# How to count NaN items in Impala query?

Tags: hdfs, nan, cloudera, impala

I have a table that has 'NaN' in a field that is a double.  I simply want to count how many items are 'NaN':

```
Select count(*) from table
where col = 'NaN'
```

AnalysisException: operands of type DOUBLE and STRING are not comparable: col = 'NaN'

```
Select count(*) from table
where col is null
```

Result = 0  (there are tons of NaN records in this column btw)

```
Select count(*) from table
where cast(col as string) = 'NaN'
```

Result = 0

How do I do this where it will actually count the NaN rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would cast the *NaNs* into string and then do the comparison with `'nan'`

```sql
Select count(*) from table
where cast(col as string) = 'nan'
```

Comment: I was using 'NaN' which is how it appears in the data, but when cast as a string, it is all lowercase.  that was my issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the is_nan function

```
select count(*) from table
where is_nan(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way to count..

```
select sum(if(is_nan(column_name), 1, 0)) as nan_count, count(column_name) AS total_count
from table_name;
```